# Редирект только при https в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, https, редирект

Возникла нетипичная ситуация. Нужно по протоколу http редиректить на www, а по протоколу https наоборот с www на без www

Я не мастер редиректов, написал как-то так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Я думал по логике, что первое условие должно сработать если http и второе если https, но не пашет. Если убрать первое условие, то второе работает, но тогда не работает первое естессно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот редирект по `http://` на `http://www`

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

А этот кусок делает редирект с `https://www` на `https://`

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

И если примените оба то два раза не надо писать `RewriteEngine on`.